# Read a list of n numbers and make an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, input, printf, scanf

So I want to take an input such as this:

The first input tells us the size of the array and the second line contains the numbers of array like this:

input:

```
3
1 2 3
```

And I want to make an array from the second input line with a size of from the first input line.

I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", n);
        int x[n];
        int y[n];

}
```

But after which I get stumped.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a VLA(Variable Length Array) supporting compiler(eg. GCC):

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n];
scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]);
```

and if not,

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]);
```

This code uses the functionality of `scanf` to be able to take multiple delimited input.

If you have to take `n` inputs and not only set the size of `arr` to `n`, do this:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &n[i]);
}
```

It should be apparent that VLA functionality lets you to make an array on the stack with a runtime value. Otherwise, you'll need to allocate it on the heap with `malloc()`.

Comment: What if there are more than 3 numbers to scan. Do I need to add more "%d" and arr[] or is there some way for it to work with any number of numbers in the second line.

Comment: @MidoriyaUzumaki No need. Just use `scanf` with a single %d and use it in a loop n times.

Comment: @MidoriyaUzumaki Actually, you made me realise that this answer is kind of incomplete. It's still correct, because you only specify the size as being necessary. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

> What if there are more than 3 numbers to scan. Do I need to add more
> "%d" and arr[] or is there some way for it to work with any number of
> numbers in the second line.

To address this point you can go with iterating over loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
```